# mpicc command not found

Tags: c, openmpi, mpich

I installed openmpi 4.1.0 and when I went to compile a C program with mpicc the terminal says mpicc command is not found. I have a MacBook and I am currently on Big Sur. I tried homebrew but that didn't go well (for some reason Homebrew does not recognize the formula openmpi or mpich). I tried downloading from their website and following the directions step by step, but I am still unable to find out why the terminal spits out mpicc command is not found. Can anyone help me solve this issue? I need to solve this issue soon because I have a homework assignment that requires this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you install?  Does your PATH include that directory?

Comment: My library folder. And it does include that directory @AllanWind

Comment: I don't actually know anything about MacOS.  Can you execute the binary with a full path (in a terminal)?